# How can i create static marker in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I don't have a great level in javascript and OpenLayers, and i am trying to realize a map with static markers pointing airports in all the world.
Well i tried to search my answer but i can't resolve my problem.

I already tried to find docs or examples, but every time it doesn't work.

Please if anybody can help me by telling me how to create markers based on a list of data?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Do you have this list of data?

Comment: Yes i do.  thanks for your answer.

Comment: And what format is it? GeoJSON, TopoJSON, KML ...

Comment: it's a geoJSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/vtfuqbuj/))

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: 'url_of_your_file'
  })
});
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

This way you can load a GeoJSON file into your map.

If you want, say, a circle marker you add a style to [`ol.layer.Vector`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html) like:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: 'url_of_your_file'
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 10,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ffff00'
      })
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: @InèsZarka you're welcome, if this is what you expected, mark the answer as correct and finish it.