# How to change map in openlayer example with own geoJson map?

Tags: maps, openlayers-3, geojson

I want to use the pre coded example popup http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html for MY map. I have a .shp (shape file) converted to GEOJSON format. I want the code to be replaced for adding same type of pop up to my map.
note:i altered this code n changed url. but this doesn't work.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
        url: 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/' +
            'mapbox.natural-earth-hypso-bathy.json',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
      })
    })
  ],
  overlays: [overlay],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37969185/4640499) how do you add your geojson to the map and then you can [see this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37988635/4640499) on how to add a click listener.

Comment: 2nd link didn't work though 1st was really useful.Thanks a lot for such quick reply! one query:  in 4 line code of adding geojson map, local url isn't working. Kindly give me solution for the same

Comment: That URL you have to change to point to your geojson file.

Comment: got it :D thank you so much