# Creating an event on a map maker

Tags: javascript, json, maps, openlayers-3

```js
//Final Code 

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 3
    })
});
// -- GeoJSON layer --

// Define a GeoJSON source that will load features via a http call. By
// specifying the projection of the map's view OL3 will transform the coordinates
// for display
var planningAppsSource = new ol.source.GeoJSON({
    'projection': map.getView().getProjection(),
    'url': 'http://localhost/osgis-ol3-leaflet-master/ol3/data.geojson'
});

// Create a vector layer to display the features within the GeoJSON source and
// applies a simple icon style to all features
var planningAppsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: planningAppsSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(({
            anchor: [0.5, 40],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            src: 'marker-icon.png'
        }))
    })
});

// Add the layer to the map
map.addLayer(planningAppsLayer);

var input = document.getElementById('input-airports');

map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
        evt.pixel, function(ft, l) { return ft; });
  if (feature) {
    console.log(feature.getProperties());
    
    input.value = feature.get('desc');
  }
});
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
  if (e.dragging) return;
  var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent));
});
```

I succeed creating a simple map with OL3 with static markers pointing airports which take them data in an external JSON file.

But now i would like that when i click on a marker, create a function which find the name of the airport corresponding to the marker, in my JSON file and show it in an external field type:input.

I already tried to create a click event on my marker, an open layers interaction, try to take back some data in my Json File. but it seems like i'm missing something, all my little parts doesn't fit all together.

I don't know where i can start :s

Thank you all for your answers.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 3
    })
});
// -- GeoJSON layer --

// Define a GeoJSON source that will load features via a http call. By
// specifying the projection of the map's view OL3 will transform the coordinates
// for display
var planningAppsSource = new ol.source.GeoJSON({
    'projection': map.getView().getProjection(),
    'url': 'http://localhost/osgis-ol3-leaflet-master/ol3/data.geojson'
});

// Create a vector layer to display the features within the GeoJSON source and
// applies a simple icon style to all features
var planningAppsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: planningAppsSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(({
            anchor: [0.5, 40],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            src: 'marker-icon.png'
        }))
    })
});

// Add the layer to the map
map.addLayer(planningAppsLayer);


// Map Click event 
planningAppsSource.addEventListener(map, 'click', function(event){
  var getHttpRequest = function () {
  var httpRequest = false;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (httpRequest.overrideMimeType) {
      httpRequest.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
    }
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
    try {
      httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e) {
      try {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (e) {}
    }
  }

  if (!httpRequest) {
    alert('Abandon :( Impossible de créer une instance XMLHTTP');
    return false;
  }

  return httpRequest
}
    });
```

GeoJSON:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -145.494,
         -17.3595


        ]
      },
    "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "code": "AAA",
    "lon": "-17.3595",
    "lat": "-145.494",
    "name": "Anaa Airport",
    "city": "Anaa",
    "state": "Tuamotu-Gambier",
    "country": "French Polynesia", 
    "woeid": "12512819",
    "tz": "Pacific\/Midway",
    "phone": "",
    "type": "Airports",
    "email": "",
    "url": "",
    "runway_length": "4921",
    "elev": "7",
    "icao": "NTGA",
    "direct_flights": "2",
    "carriers": "1"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please show some code that you tried, maybe it leads to the direction.

Comment: i just did ! thks :) here you have the code where i call my map, create my markers, and where i try to add a click event in my markers

Comment: Show us a portion of your JSON file, specifically an airport.

Comment: i just post a portion of my json file present the call of two airports,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add these two listeners (and remove all that `planningAppsSource.addEventListener` stuff):

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
        evt.pixel, function(ft, l) { return ft; });
  if (feature) {
    // just to show all your feature's properties
    console.log(feature.getProperties());

    // to get a specific property
    var name = feature.get('name');
    var city = feature.get('city');
  }
});

// you don't actually need this
// this is only to change the cursor to a pointer when is over a feature
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
  if (e.dragging) return;
  var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent));
  map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

Comment: Working thank u so much :) now i need to make those information appears in my input :)

Comment: Just set the value: `document.getElementById('id-input').value = name`

Comment: it didn't work by changing this : 
document.getElementById('input-airports').value = name

Comment: Do you have a `<input type="text" id="input-airports">` in your `html`? Also, did you `console.log(name)`?

Comment: document.getElementById('input-airports').value = name
 console.log(name) and  <input type="text" id="input-airports"/> this is my input. still nothing appaers in my field :/ :(

Comment: i tried to implement the pieces that i needed from the fiddle, it's almost working perfectly just when i click in a marker i have an undefined that appears in my field instead of the name of the airport :/

Comment: I post my entire file just to be sure

Comment: But `feature.get('desc')` is not what you want. You want `feature.get('name')`.

Comment: Yeah, i didn't pay attention :/ it's working perfectly thank you a lot for your help :)

Comment: hi, i have another question. Is there a possibility to select to multiple items at a time and make all appear in my field. if yes, what do i change ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @InèsZarka, I guess it's better you create another question because it's out of this question's scope.

Comment: I can't for the moment, but i will ASAP. :)